# Feynman rules for Nucleon-Nucleon Interaction with Tensor Coupling

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, nuclear-physics, feynman-diagrams

Hello im trying to Compute the Cross section of an elastic Nucleon-Nucleon scattering and i don't know what to make of the following Lagrangian:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{\rho N N}=-g_{\rho} \bar{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \boldsymbol{\tau} \psi \cdot \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{\mu}^{(\rho)}-\frac{f_{\rho}}{4 m} \bar{\psi} \sigma^{\mu \nu} \tau \psi \cdot\left(\partial_{\mu} \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{\nu}^{(\rho)}-\partial_{\nu} \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{\mu}^{(\rho)}\right)
\end{equation}

Specifcally the second term is the one which complicates things for me. What i know is that the derivative includes a term of the momentum of the vector boson but i don't know how to continue from there. What im reading suggests the vertex should be of this from
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^\mu=i\frac{f_a}{2m}\sigma^{\mu\nu}(q'-q)_\nu
\end{equation}
But i can't understand how a object with 2 indices namely
$\left(\partial_{\mu} \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{\nu}^{(\rho)}-\partial_{\nu} \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{\mu}^{(\rho)}\right)$ became $(q'-q)_\nu$. Also $\sigma_{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{2}[\gamma_\mu,\gamma_\nu]$

I found out also about Gordon decomposition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_decomposition which greatly helps once you actually calculated $\Gamma_\mu$ but i still don't understand why we don't get
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^\mu=i\frac{f_a}{4m}\sigma^{\mu\nu}(k_\mu\varphi_\nu-k_\nu\varphi_\mu)
\end{equation}
Which can't be right though.